# "403 forbidden" error while install QGis Server on Windows 10

Tags: qgis-server

I'm trying to install QGIS server on Windows 10, I followed many instruction (Including official QGIS documentation) but always get 403 forbidden. Anyone have up-to-date step by step instruction ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I'm struggling to get an answer about 403 too.
I followed documentation [Installation instructions](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/server_manual/getting_started.html#installation-on-windows) for windows install in docs but I ran into the same problem. It must be something about folder permissions, but I can’t figure this out and it’s making me crazy. Did you solve this problem? I can't use docker or linux so I'm stuck :( I will post apache error log later if necessary.